# jQuery datepicker doesn't work in Modal MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-datepicker

DatePicker works around the project, but does not work in a modal. The Modal is a partial View.

This in a editor template.

DateTime.cshtml

```
@model System.DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "editor-field" })

    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof (jQuery) == 'function') {
            $(function () {
                if ($.datepicker) {
                    $('#@this.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("")')
                    .datepicker();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you try adding a custom class to your textbox and add the script on the actual partial view instead of on the Editor template? you will need now to call the jquery function with the class instead the id

Comment: @pollirrata thanks friend, can you help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on your Editor Template

```
@model System.DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "editor-field picker" })
```

and on the Shared view call the script like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof (jQuery) == 'function') {
            $(function () {
                if ($.datepicker) {
                    $('input.picker')
                    .datepicker();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Now I get the calendar, but I can not clic :(